# How to run iOS unit tests with cocoapods that include UI references?

Tags: ios, unit-testing, static-libraries, cocoapods

I'm trying to run unit tests on my iOS library that includes cocoapod dependencies. The main library target builds fine, but I get this error when running unit tests:

`Unknown Device Type. Using UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone based on screen size`

I believe this is because one of my libraries is running UI tests and that the simulator is not capable of handling them. The crash actually originates from this line of code in one of the pods:

`[appearance setItemFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14]];`

So how can I exclude a pod from testing so that I can run basic logic tests on my classes that have nothing to do with UI?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to exclude a Pod from your testing target? This is [outlined in the Podfile guide](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#target).